# Считаем при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Имеется разметка

`<button onclick="doCount()">Считаем</button>
    <p id="count">Всего попыток: </p>`

и функция

```
function doCount(){
var count=document.getElementById('count'),
counNum=0;

count.innerHTML+=counNum++;}
```

Почему при нажатии на клавишу выводятся нули? Нужно, чтобы выводился инкремент.

Comment: потому что вы каждый раз в переменную counNum записываете 0. Нужно ее обьявить до функции.

Comment: Да. Заработало. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`counNum` постоянно перезаписывается в Вашем случае

```js
let counNum=0;
function doCount(){

let count=document.getElementById('count');

count.innerHTML+=counNum++;}
```

```html
<button onclick="doCount()">Считаем</button>
    <p id="count">Всего попыток: </p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Я бы все-таки посоветовал избавится от "приплюсовывания" к `innerHTML`. Добавил `span` элемент.

Суть: берем этот `span` по ид, конвертим текущее значение к `int` с помощью `+`, прибавляем `1` и сетаем этому элементу.

```js
function doCount() {
  var count = document.getElementById('count');
  count.innerHTML = +count.innerHTML + 1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="doCount()">Считаем</button>
<p>Всего попыток: <span id="count"></span></p>
```